# A-frame render lop and view refresh

Tags: render, aframe, virtual-reality

I am trying to create a First person view in A-frame using the .obj model of a car.

The camera has been positioned close to the driver's seat, and there is a timed interval in javascript that moves the camera position by doing trignometric calculations and moves the camera accordingly.

Here are two problems I am facing

1) How do you make this smoother? Is there a hook for the render loop in A-frame which can be accessed in javascript? I cant seem to find the documentation for it.

2) When I view the above page in VR mode on the phone ( Android 9), the animation created stops abruptly, which works well in fullscreen mode.

The code for the html is here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CuriosityGym/VRWithAframe/master/templates/class3-models.html

The example can be accessed here  http://cgaframe.herokuapp.com/class3

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `setInterval` that fires every 100ms, animating the car at 10fps. That’s why it’s not smooth. Create a component and  use the [tick](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/component.html#tick-time-timedelta) method to [animate](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#defining-a-behavior-with-the-tick-handler)

In addition, you should not animate the camera directy because its position will be overriden by the headset pose in VR mode. Setup and animate a [camera rig](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/primitives/a-camera.html#manually-positioning-the-camera)

Comment: Thank You! Will try your recommendations.

Comment: I created the modifications as you suggested, but the scene does not refresh when in VR mode on phone. I have borrowed the inclination of the camera and applied it to the rig. Is that how it should have been done?

Comment: Notice that your code is taking the rotation and applying it to position. Access and modify the object3D instead of using setAttribute. e.g: this.el.object3D.position.x Don’t rotate users head, it won’t be a good experience. especially in VR.

Comment: I am using polar co-ordinates to determine the cartesian co ordinates from the angle the camera is pointing at. I then use these cartesian co ordinates to move the camera linearly. Have not mapped a joystick yet to control the magnitude of the linear movement. I dont think I am modifying the angle of the users head.